# Can Mono.Data.Sqlite be used with Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mono, .net-standard

I was searching for a Sqlite library that will work with Xamarin. I've tried three of them:

- System.Data.Sqlite, which doesn't work at all
- sqlite-net, which works as expected but doesn't support DataReaders

Finally, I tried Mono.Data.Sqlite which shows a lot of error messages, but I can still start the project and querying the sqlite database works as well.
Now I'm wondering if there will be any problems by using this library with Xamarin, or if I can ignore the error messages at all.

These are the error messages shown by Visual Studio:

> Error NU1202  Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 is not compatible with monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
>
> NU1202    Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win. Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
>
> Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
>
> Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x86. Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
>
> Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0) / win-x64. Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
>
> ackage Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 is not compatible with xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0). Package Mono.Data.Sqlite 1.0.61 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)

Comment: sqlite-net-pcl can do text based SQL queries.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I need a DataReader to read the results, and the library does not provide a DataReader.